# Display Min Max characters from a column - Google Sheets Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For designing purposes, I need to know the minimum and maximum possible text from a paragraph. I've added an image below to show you what I try to achieve. A:6 has the minimum characters (2) whereas A:4 has the most characters (30). On B:4 I want to display the min-max range.

[image: Example]

I've been looking and trying formula's, but none working so far. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you kindly in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(MIN(LEN(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")))&"-"&MAX(LEN(A2:A)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thnx again mate, you're my hero!

Answer (score 2):

Use:
=max(ArrayFormula(len(A4:A7))) for maximum

=min(ArrayFormula(len(A4:A7))) for minimum

[image]

Or if you want to have everything in one cell, you can try:
="Text length range "&min(ArrayFormula(len(A4:A7)))&"-"&max(ArrayFormula(len(A4:A7)))&" characters."

Comment: Thnx for the examples!